# Ubuntu - how to fix this problem with HP Elite 800 all in one? often i get black screen with mouse cursor only

Tags: drivers, 13.10, kernel, hp, crash

How to get the desktop always? Instead of after reboot it shows mouse cursor only and black screen nothing else works unless i go to ctrl+alt+f1 and use it as command line.

version:

```
Linux hpelitee800 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg:

```
[ 2891.038975] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x503c000 ctx 1) at 0x503c220
[ 2945.012604] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2945.012720] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x5094000 ctx 1) at 0x5094220
[ 2951.035024] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2951.035109] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x503c000 ctx 1) at 0x503c220
[ 2969.970001] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2969.970113] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x1074000 ctx 0) at 0x1074230
[ 2975.968416] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2975.968509] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x5063000 ctx 1) at 0x5063220
[ 2981.966825] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2981.966933] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x5094000 ctx 1) at 0x5094220
[ 2988.013224] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2988.013310] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x507b000 ctx 1) at 0x507b220
[ 2994.011639] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2994.011733] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x5094000 ctx 1) at 0x5094220
[ 2999.998048] [drm:i915_hangcheck_elapsed] *ERROR* stuck on render ring
[ 2999.998123] [drm:i915_set_reset_status] *ERROR* render ring hung inside bo (0x507b000 ctx 1) at 0x507b220
[ 3000.018028] [drm:__gen6_gt_force_wake_mt_get] *ERROR* Timed out waiting for forcewake old ack to clear.
```

Comment: I get the same error on my hp pavillion laptop. I guess X configuration is screwed.

Comment: YES - its horrible they do not have stable X yet.

Comment: One solution would be to boot via live usb  and copy all x configuration files...